# "could not connect to DB TypeError:[objectOptions,urlOptions,exports.DEFAULT_OPTIONS].flatMap is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, joi

I was trying to install "**express-joi-validation**" and when trying to run the app again with "**node app.js**", I get the error.
Although it works before installing "**express-joi-validation**"

Comment: Hi Muhannad, Could you share the error? You might also want to try `npm install -s express-joi-validation`

Comment: Thanks for your replying, the problem has been solved by upgrading the version of node - @Xanik